# Ajax Script make my server to much busy. Have any others process to do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 3 notification with drop-down window with detail like facebook.

1. for Friend
2. for Massage
3. for Wall notification

So update notification I used Ajax, But I think It's make my server more busy. I also learn and spend many days about comet, long poll, web socket etc but I cannot apply them in my web because of my weak knowledge.

Please give a guideline?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    $('.count1').load('/notificationfollow.php');
    $('.notif1').load('/updatefollow.php');
    }, 56000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    $('.count5').load('/notificationmail.php');
    $('.notif5').load('/updatemail.php');
    }, 36000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    $('.count3').load('/notificationcount.php');
    $('.notif').load('/updatenotification.php');
    }, 11000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
});
```

notificationmail.php

```
<?php
include("db.php");
include_once("include/session.php");
// This script create by and all right reserve by 
?>
<?
global $dbh;
$userid=$session->bdid;
$query = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE `to` = '".$userid."'     && `to_viewed` = '0' ORDER BY `created` DESC") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
$count6 = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count6 > 0)
{
echo '<span class="badge notification_count">'.$count6.'</span>';
} else
{ echo '';
}
?>
```

And notification mail html

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
<div class="count5">
<?php 
include_once("notificationmail.php");
if($count6 > 0)
{
echo '<span class="badge notification_count">'.$count1.'</span>';
} else
{ 
echo '';
}
?></div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach is probably a lot of unnecessary overhead:

```
$('.count3').load('/notificationcount.php');
$('.notif').load('/updatenotification.php');
```

This is because the content is being loaded over and over, regardless of whether or not there's any new data.  How much data is being sent over the network every time each of these "pages" loads?

Instead of refreshing the content, just refresh the data.  Create a separate server-side "page" which responds [only with JSON data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), which can be pretty minimal.  Something as simple as:

```
// assuming you have some means to "get notifications"
$notificationCount = getNotifications();
echo json_encode($notificationCount);
```

In client-side code you'd then just need to get that data:

```
// assuming the name of the new server-side resource here
$.get('/notificationcount_json.php', function (response) {
    // use the data in the response to change the UI
});
```

Now instead of returning all of the HTML markup which the client-side page *already has*, the AJAX call is *only* returning the data.  If there's no data, it might be an empty response.  Or for a list of notifications could be as small as:

```
[]
```

At that point all you need to do in that `$.get()` callback function is update the UI as needed.  For example, if `response` is an array and you just need to update a `div` to hold the count, it might look something like:

```
$.get('/notificationcount_json.php', function (response) {
    $('#someDiv').text(response.length);
});
```

Not knowing anything about either your server-side or client-side code, I can't be much more specific.  But the general idea is to only fetch data which the client doesn't already have.  The client does already have the HTML to display to the user, all it needs is updated notification data.

---

**Update:** Given the additional code you posted, here's an example.  In `notificationmail.php` the only information which the client needs is the numeric value.  It doesn't need that `span` tag because it already has one.  So just return that value as JSON data:

```
$count6 = mysqli_num_rows($query);
echo json_encode($count6);
```

The client-side code then just needs to use the value to update the UI, rather than replace the UI.  Something like this:

```
$.get('/notificationmail.php', function (data) {
    $('.count5').text(data);
});
```

This effectively reduces that particular AJAX response from dozens of bytes to a couple of bytes.  It's a small change in that case, but that's probably the simplest one.  The rest would likely see larger improvements.

Furthermore, once all of this information has been organized as structured data instead of raw HTML, you can probably move it all into a *single* AJAX call which returns one large structured object, instead of many individual AJAX calls which return individual values.  That would reduce the overhead significantly.

Comment: I want to read more about your script. Thank you sir, I am trying as you say.

Comment: @koc: What specifically isn't working?  I can elaborate if there's something you're not understanding about the answer.

Comment: Sir, I update with one of my notification php (notificationmail.php) and html code. Can you make it easy with your script please.

Comment: @koc: I've updated the answer with what appears to be the smallest example from your code.

Comment: I am so weak about jquery, JS. But I am trying with your script. Thank you sir.

Comment: Sir, It's not update a time interval. update only new page load. And How to put `.text(date)` into `<span class="badge></span>` and how to apply here if data=0, span not display.

Comment: @koc: According to your code this code does run at regular intervals.  You might want to look up what `setInterval()` does.  It's not clear what else you're asking.  The `.text()` function does put the content into the matched element(s).  For wrapping that in a conditional, that's what an `if` statement is for.